# SharePoint 3.0 Search Stuck Starting

Tags: windows-server-2003, sharepoint-2007, search, sharepoint

I have a single server running SharePoint 3.0 on WS2003 Sp2 not on a domain. My search service stopped working so I just went in to central admin and hit stop, then hit start. I soon found out this is not the way to do this process. I now can not get the search service to start again. I have tried everything I can think of, and nothing works it changes status to Starting but never gets to started. I have to go in with "stsadm -o spsearch  -action stop" from the command prompt to stop it. I am using the Local service account for the service and the content accounts. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Anything in the event logs that could point to an issue?

Best preactice is to have a local account that is a member of the local administrators group for stuff like search So maybe SPSEARCH for the search account.  We had a SharePoint system that used one account for everything and then when we had to troubleshoot, we could not easily tell what was having the issue.  Can you create a local account and add it to the Local Administrator group and use that for the service?

Comment: Content index on Search could not be initialized. Error Access is denied.   0x80070005.Component: 04e49b89-102e-4eb3-b055-34e1d06861ae

Well can't believe I missed that. But it is using the local service account. Advice?

Comment: Do I need to give that account access to the database as well? Should I use it for the Service Account and the Content Access account when I start the service from central admin, and for the Sharepoint Search Service that i can edit in services.msc?